# Unable to access signapk.jar

Tags: android, android-source

So, I am trying to create an OTA package in AOSP and I run into this error at the very end.

```
2020-07-23 09:09:28 - common.py - INFO    : using prebuilt boot.img from IMAGES...
2020-07-23 09:09:28 - common.py - INFO    :   boot size (13910016) is 20.73% of limit (67108864)
2020-07-23 09:09:29 - ota_from_target_files.py - ERROR   : 
   ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 2263, in <module>
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 2243, in main
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 1986, in GenerateNonAbOtaPackage
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 884, in WriteFullOTAPackage
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 1332, in FinalizeMetadata
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 1318, in ComputeAllPropertyFiles
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 495, in SignOutput
  File "/home/shen/android-11/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/common.py", line 1898, in SignFile
    proc.returncode, stdoutdata))
ExternalError: Failed to run signapk.jar: return code 1:
Error: Unable to access jarfile out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar

Compressing system.new.dat with brotli
Compressing vendor.new.dat with brotli
09:09:30 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (01:44 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I checked and there is no signapk.jar created in the out directory.

Comment: Did you call `make dist`? Did you try `make out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar`?

Comment: yes, after posting this question it stuck to my mind that i should try doing make signapk.jar and it built the otapackage after it. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in case anybody face it in future. Building the signapk.jar separately fixes the issue. So do a make signapk.jar

Comment: Building the signapk.jar separately will work by doing mma or mm and that will be a workaround
because before building otapackage one should go and build signapk.jar separately and this is not the case with earlier android versions it used built along with make otapackage
looks likes this is broken in Android 11

Comment: well you can define signapk as a build target in your device tree and that would solve this issue.

Comment: I am not sure how to define to target for a jar to built into a particular out folder..
for example ota_from_target_files search signapk.jar for out/host/linux-x86/framework and its dependencies to out/host/linux-x86/lib
but we can change search path in ota_from_target_files ..
what I am trying to tell is that without modifying all this(AOSP) it used to work in earlier android versions but in android 11 it is not working.
raised a [google ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168728393) for this

Comment: https://github.com/ZHANtech-Organization/android_device_xiaomi_santoni/commit/8013c792ddda720ad9149104cce142fd7e2b8a2e
refer to this commit for building signapk.

Comment: it was already added as target in android 11 http://192.99.106.107:8080/xref/android-11.0.0_r3/xref/build/core/Makefile

Comment: Even then for some reasons it don't build unless defined in the device.mk

Comment: yes, this was not the case in earlier versions